# dovecot imap ssl certificate issues

Tags: ubuntu, imap, ssl, dovecot

i have been trying to configure my dovecot imap server (version 1.0.10 - upgrading is not an option at this stage) with a new ssl certificate on ubuntu like so:

```
$ grep ^ssl /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
ssl_disable = no
ssl_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com.crt.20120904
ssl_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.com.key.20120904
$ /etc/init.t/dovecot stop
$ sudo dovecot -p
$ [i enter the ssl password here]
```

it doesn't show any errors and when i run `ps aux | grep dovecot` i get

```
root     21368  0.0  0.0  12452   688 ?        Ss   15:19   0:00 dovecot -p
root     21369  0.0  0.0  71772  2940 ?        S    15:19   0:00 dovecot-auth
dovecot  21370  0.0  0.0  14140  1904 ?        S    15:19   0:00 pop3-login
dovecot  21371  0.0  0.0  14140  1900 ?        S    15:19   0:00 pop3-login
dovecot  21372  0.0  0.0  14140  1904 ?        S    15:19   0:00 pop3-login
dovecot  21381  0.0  0.0  14280  2140 ?        S    15:19   0:00 imap-login
dovecot  21497  0.0  0.0  14280  2116 ?        S    15:29   0:00 imap-login
dovecot  21791  0.0  0.0  14148  1908 ?        S    15:48   0:00 imap-login
dovecot  21835  0.0  0.0  14148  1908 ?        S    15:53   0:00 imap-login
dovecot  21931  0.0  0.0  14148  1904 ?        S    16:00   0:00 imap-login
me       21953  0.0  0.0   5168   944 pts/0    S+   16:02   0:00 grep --color=auto dovecot
```

which looks like it is all running fine. so then i test to see if i can telnet to the dovecot server, and this works fine:

```
$ telnet localhost 143
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK Dovecot ready.
```

but when i test whether dovecot has configured the ssl certificates properly, it appears to fail:

```
$ sudo openssl s_client -connect localhost:143 -starttls imap
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /description=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/C=AU/ST=xxxxxxxx/L=xxxx/O=xxxxxx/CN=*.mydomain.com/emailAddress=postmaster@mydomain.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /description=xxxxxxxxxxx/C=AU/ST=xxxxxx/L=xxxx/O=xxxx/CN=*.mydomain.com/emailAddress=postmaster@mydomain.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 /description=xxxxxxxx/C=AU/ST=xxxxxxxxxx/L=xxxx/O=xxxxx/CN=*.mydomain.com/emailAddress=postmaster@mydomain.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/description=xxxxxxxxxxxx/C=AU/ST=xxxxxxxxxx/L=xxxxxxxx/O=xxxxxxx/CN=*.mydomain.com/emailAddress=postmaster@mydomain.com
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 2 Primary Intermediate Server CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
.
.
.
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/description=xxxxxxxxxx/C=AU/ST=xxxxxxxxx/L=xxxxxxx/O=xxxxxx/CN=*.mydomain.com/emailAddress=postmaster@mydomain.com
issuer=/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 2 Primary Intermediate Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2831 bytes and written 342 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1351661960
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
. OK Capability completed.
```

at least, i'm assuming this is a failure???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with openssl, not dovecot.

There is [a bug](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=977&user=guest&pass=guest) in openssl which stops it looking for the default CApath, so you need to tell it where to find the list of root CA certs by adding `-CApath` to your command line. For example:

```
sudo openssl s_client -connect localhost:143 -starttls imap -CApath /dev/null
```

If you have not populated your certs folder yet and you are computer literate, then follow [this tutorial](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/cacerts.html) to download certdata.txt from Mozilla and generate the necessary PEM files and symlinks. The scripts may need modifying if you do not have access to /bin and you will need to create a symlink ln -s ca-bundle.crt cert.pem.

(Specifying /dev/null forces openssl to use the default path of cert.pem in your openssl directory. To find out where your openssl directory is, type `openssl version -d`).

Since you are using StartSSL, you may need to concatenate your certificate and their intermediate certificate for dovecot, in your case StartCom Class 2 Primary Intermediate Server CA. Their free certificate uses StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA

Comment: excellent :) i ran through the tutorial and now when run the `openssl...` command i get `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`. to cat the certificates do i just go `cat /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com.crt.20120904 /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com.intermediate.20120904.pem > /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com.crt.20120904`? of course i will save the original crt just in case...

Answer (score 0):

You may use `verbose_ssl = yes` in the dovecot configuration to produce additional logging output.

In my configuration (dovecot 2.0) I use the following statements:

```
 ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com.crt.20120904
 ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/mydomain.com.key.20120904
```

Comment: thanks for the attempt but that's definitely not the problem. here is what happens when i change it to this: `Error: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf line 96: Unknown setting: ssl_cert
Fatal: Invalid configuration in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`

Comment: Right, now I see you are using dovecot 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Old question - new problems (Letsencrypt certs this time):
"*Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)*"
(meaning the Intermediate Certificate (chain) is not being found/used to verify)

Here is the solution I found after much trial and error over the last 24 hours.

First let me preface what I used for testing:
I have Dovecot on another email server (Ubuntu 18.xx) and it has the SAME Dovecot `local.conf` settings other than domains/certificates used. Both use Letsencrypt certificates and both were renewed yesterday.

The Dovecot (version 2.2.33.2) on Ubuntu 18 works perfectly.
No error codes using *openssl s_client* to test email ports :993/IMAP or :995/POP.

But, on another machine (the one showing the error) I use:

OS: `Ubuntu 20.04.2`
Dovecot (Ubuntu default/repo version): `2.3.7.2 (3c910f64b)`
OpenSSL (Ubuntu default/repo version): `1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`

The error came to my attention after I had a customer complain about adding an email account to an Android phone (Google/Gmail default email app):

"Certificate cannot be trusted."

If I use the cert for web or smtp the openssl test works fine and verifies.
**This leads me to believe the issue is with Dovecot on Ubuntu 20.**

Other email clients like Thunderbird and Outlook also work fine.

I immediately decided to test with 'openssl s_client' and the error brought me here eventually.

My config looked like this on both the broken and working dovecot machines:

```
 ssl_ca = </etc/letsencrypt/live/{CertName}/fullchain.pem
 ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/{CertName}/cert.pem
 ssl_key  = </etc/letsencrypt/live/{CertName}/privkey.pem
```

I have not determined what software causes the error, but I have cleared the error. The Android phone now trusts the certificate fully. Going in I knew the error was probably caused by the lack of verification of the certificate chain / CA.

**Solution/TL;DR:**

Use the *fullchain.pem* as your certificate entry (`ssl_cert =`). It contains both your LE cert and chain.

Your Dovecot configuration for SSL should look like this (replace {CertName} with your own, obviously):

```
 ssl_ca = </etc/letsencrypt/live/{CertName}/chain.pem  (or 'fullchain' should work)
 ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/{CertName}/fullchain.pem
 ssl_key  = </etc/letsencrypt/live/{CertName}/privkey.pem
```

You should not see the error anymore during testing:

```
 Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

I didn't need to change anything on the machine not showing the error (Ubuntu 18) - so I didn't.

Update:
Dovecot being used currently with Ubuntu 20 repository/apt is/was affected.
Bug reference: https://dovecot.org/pipermail/dovecot/2021-April/121884.html